# How do I grant access to a Java Web Application hosted on a Google Compute Engine's VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, glassfish, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a Google Compute Engine VM so it behaves like a web server. What do I need to do so people can access my web application, which is hosted in it ?

I've successfully installed Glassfish on this VM and I've also been sucessfull in deploying my java web application in it. As of now, I can access my website from inside this vm, and it works perfectly. The thing is... how do i make it so every user can access this web application? What do I need to do for it to be "open to the public" ?

Comment: Update... I can sucessfully ping my vm, but I still can't acess my web app from outside

Comment: 1-Does your vm has Internal and external Ip addresses?
2-Do you have a domain with someone (like godaddy)? If so, you need to update the records in the DNS of the domain to point to the VM external ip address
Check this: https://vinoaj.com/guides/2018/google-cloud-dns-for-godaddy-domain/

Answer (score 1):

In order to expose your website you will need to reserve an  static External IP using this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address.

When you have the external IP you must configure the firewall rules. I found an useful link which explains how to do that: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to open up the correct ports.

Check what port your server is running on (The logs normally say something like "Listening on: 9000"), default port for HTTPS is 443, and HTTP is 80.

Create a firewall rule that allows ingress to the port your server is on from where-ever you want it to come from. Always be careful when opening up a server to the wild west that is the public.

Information on firewall rules are [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) and [this](https://geekflare.com/gcp-firewall-configuration/) tutorial has some descriptions and a nice step by step.

Lastly, if your server doesn't have a public IP you won't be able to reach it directly.

Good luck!